# Tor browser doesn't start, although i have the Path to tor.exe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently I wanted to make a program that opens Tor, but when I start the program it opens Firefox and has no Errors. Im pretty sure the Paths are correct, because i saw them on a other Question. Actually it works, but with the wrong browser. It worked before i wrote down the profile preference things.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

#Profile Configurations
torexe = os.popen(r'C:/Users/Seya Unknown/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:/Users/Seya Unknown/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()

#Driver Configurations
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:/Users/Seya Unknown/Webdrivers/geckodriver.exe')

#Driver get
driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
```

Comment: This answer might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316878/python-selenium-binding-with-tor-browser

Comment: It doesn't work, because my script is build on that