# Python Selenium with Tor Browser (Ubuntu)

Tags: selenium, proxy, tor, geckodriver, tor-browser-bundle

I try to open a Tor Browser using Selenium on Ubuntu 18. I have tried lots of examples but with no success.

```
proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = "9050"
profileTor = '/etc/tor/' # torrc
binary = os.path.expanduser("~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox")

firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(profileTor)
proxy_address = "127.0.0.1:9050"
proxy = Proxy({
'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
'httpProxy': proxy_address,
 })
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = firefox_binary,firefox_profile=firefox_profile, proxy = proxy)
```

A blank Tor Browser window opens but after a while I get an error as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused.
```

I have also tried an alternative to firefox binary the:

> start-tor-browser

which opens a working Tor Browser and showing some index. 
The script however stops and I cannot visit another page using Selenium unless I do it manually.

I have also tried the:

> profile.default

as some examples suggest but I get an error:

> Unable to start Tor. The torrc file is missing and could not be created.

Comment: The only workaround that I have found is this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21836296/3816638
It would probably work on all .onion links.

Comment: See also my post here, it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536691/3816638 Don't forget to check the port of the tor network.

Answer (score 0):

To open a Tor Browser using Selenium you can start the **Tor daemon** first and then open the **Tor Browser** and you can use the following solution:

- Sample WindowsOS style Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
  import os

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\AtechM_03\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
  profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
  profile.update_preferences()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
  ```