# How to use Tor with Chrome browser through Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, tor

I'm trying to run my selenium driver on Tor. Note that the script already runs with no errors without Tor.

This is what I've done so far:

1) I called the Tor framework

```
import socks
import socket
from stem.util import term    


import stem.process

SOCKS_PORT=7000 

socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,
                      addr = "127.0.0.1", 
                      port = SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket
def getaddrinfo(*args):   return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):   
    if "Bootstrapped " in line:
      print(term.format(line, term.Color.GREEN))

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd = "C:/Users/my-username\Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor//tor.exe" ,
    config = { 'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),},
    init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

2. After calling the Tor framework which is like a container to my understanding, I then called the Chrome driver:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   options = Options()
   options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = r'C:\Users\my-username\chromedriver')
   ```

3) At this point I insert the scraping script.

4) Close driver and kill the Tor process:

```
driver.close()   
tor_process.kill()
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Apr 15 14:31:20.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Apr 15 14:31:23.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Apr 15 14:31:23.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Apr 15 14:31:23.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Apr 15 14:31:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-2b2233fc0ae4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/my-username-folder/FireStarter_All_1Step_2.py', wdir='C:/Users/my-username-folder')

  File "C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/my-username-folder/FireStarter_All_1Step_2.py", line 94, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = r'C:\Users\my-username-folder\chromedriver')

  File "C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File "C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)

WebDriverException: Can not connect to the Service C:\Users\my-username-folder\chromedriver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update:
I am looking to use Tor with Chrome browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use **Tor** with *Chrome* browser through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import os

  # To use Tor's SOCKS proxy server with chrome, include the socks protocol in the scheme with the --proxy-server option
  # PROXY = "socks5://127.0.0.1:9150" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Debanjan.B\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Tor_Chrome]

---

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)

Comment: I had to change the port number. \nPROXY = "socks5://localhost:9150"

Comment: How would I request a new IP? Atm. it always will start with the same IP

Comment: This is the simplest and the best answer in my view, I was struggling with firefox.

Comment: This works for me but I am unable to open a website "Access Denied", any solution to this?

Comment: @SkittlesBrah Sounds to be a different issue. Can you raise a new question?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625098/selenium-chrome-firefox-webpage-access-with-tor-denied-without-works-fine

Answer (score 0):

Things I'd look at first.

1. ports - is the tor socks port interfering with the webdriver ports in any way?
2. process order ( can you setup the webdriver and then start the tor service)
3. you could setup a selenium hub that connects to selenium nodes through tor
   this might make the connection between the webdriver, tor, and your test easier to separate.

Comment: I did 2 but got same error. please explain in more detail/example how to go about 1 and 3.

Comment: 1) SOCKS_PORT is set to 7000 , do you set ports in your selenium config? If so , does it conflict. I didn't see any port related information in your error trace.  But if the webdriver can't connect to the chrome executable it can be due to a port conflict, or sometimes the chromedriver is old and doesn't match the webdriver version.

Comment: Yes for the Socks_port but there's no port setting in the selenium config so i fail to see how they interfere with each other.

Comment: 3) check out [https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp] . the selenium grid is a way to run multiple browsers and do more concurrent testing. But at this point it might be more confusion that help.