# using the Firefox Profile and the tor daemon doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tor

I want to use tor browser to bypass censorship but using the Firefox Profile and the tor daemon doesn't work. here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\fathollahy\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\fathollahy\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
```

Browser Snapshot:
[doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JERow.png)

and normal sites don't open and just loading.
I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689701/how-to-use-tor-with-chrome-browser-through-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You should change the sock_port to 9150.

Comment: the problem with normal sites solved, but I cannot connect to censored sites.