# Bypass click & hold python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, captcha

so I want to scrape a website, but there's a problem, whenever I try to enter the website, there is a "click & hold" captcha, which I cannot solve.
[image]

I already add these arguments in my code

```
option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
option.add_argument("--incognito")
option.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
option.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
option.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

I already tried to solve the captcha using actionchain in selenium, but there is no indication that the button is clicked.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#px-captcha')
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.click_and_hold(element).perform()
time.sleep(14)
action.release(element).perform()
time.sleep(0.2)
action.release(element)
```

anyone knows how to solve this using selenium, not pyautogui?

the website that I'm trying to enter:
https://www.chegg.com/study

Comment: I think you'd need proxy or something to get rid off that. May be Tor browser.

Comment: What's the advantage of using Tor browser tho?

Comment: Do you understand what Tor browser is ? and what's the main purpose of that ?

Comment: is it this one? https://www.torproject.org/download/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689701/how-to-use-tor-with-chrome-browser-through-selenium

Comment: @cruisepandley I don't see how this answers the question. Nothing guarantees that accessing the site through TOR will bypass the captcha. This might even lead to the opposite effect and bring on more severe checks.

Comment: I just used Tor, and still it doesn't work :/

Comment: please add example website

Comment: https://www.chegg.com/study

Comment: @mozway : That was the reference not the answer. Also I believe that is not a captcha. Using Tor bridge one can bypass this, I believe so. I do not enough time to argue on this or work on this at this very moment.

Comment: sorry to bother, but can you explain more about Tor bridge?

Comment: Does it change your Ip or something?

Comment: @JonathanKho Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: @ColbyHill unfortunately no, I abandoned the project

Answer (score 0):

One can also use Chromedriver Undetected..
Quite simple to integrate

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

You can follow the below git link for setup.
https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
```

Comment: now a days UC also doesnt work with PX Captcha